# setDefaultValues when using Fragment settings structure

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-settings

Android guidelines are now to design the Settings for both phone and Tablet, using Fragments for different categories/group of settings.
The SettingsActivity created by Android Studio creates one XML file for each one of settings fragment:

```
pref_general.xml
pref_notifications.xml
```

**So how the method `setDefaultValues(context,resId,readAgain)` is supposed to be used to create the first shared preferences file?**

If you put in your code, on `MainACtivity`

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.pref_general, false);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.pref_notifications, false);
```

only the first line will create a shared preferences file, with only the settings defined on that fragment.
The second line will not be executed (because the `readAgain` parameter is false, and the method has been executed already by the first line)

On the other hand, setting `readAgain` to `true` will execute `setDefaultValues` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:defaultValue` in Xml file.

`android:defaultValue`:The default value for the preference, which will 
be set either if persistence is off or persistence is on and the preference 
is not found in the persistent storage.

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat
     android:key="key1"
     android:title="Switch Preference"
     android:summary="Switch Summary"
     android:defaultValue="true" />
```

Or Programatically it can be done in this way:

```
//this returns whatever preference was set for key1 in PreferencesPage
or the default value if nothing was set 

sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key1", true));
```

Comment: Your first suggestion does not create a sharepreferences file, `SetDefaultValues()` does. Your second suggestion is impractical if you have many settings, and you have to add code every time you add a new setting. And finally, the question was not **How to initialize preferences?** but how to use `SetDefaultValues()` along the new recommendations for settings fragments

Answer (score 0):

This is an under-addressed issue with `setDefaultValues()`, where this method is only called once ever when `readAgain = false`.

When the method is called, Android system stores a key `KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES` and sets its value true. [(More info on this key here)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager?hl=en#KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES)

Now if you have more than 1 XML resource, this becomes a problem because the key is not specific to each individual XML resource.

Since we can't modify the key `KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES`, you have to set `readAgain` to true and store your own key-pair that indicates whether the default values were set or not.

```java
// Some generic code
if (firstTimeOpen) {
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.pref_general, true);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.pref_advanced, true);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.pref_notifications, true);
}
```

where `firstTimeOpen` is some boolean that indicates whether all the sharedprefs have been initialized yet.